# Move form to the right of work area

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

I would like to move a form to the rightmost monitor and to the rightmost border of the work area.

Using VB6, I used a code by vbAccelerator.com like this:

```
    Dim mThis As cMonitor = _cM.MonitorForWindow(Form.Hwnd)

    Dim lMaxRight As Integer
    If Not (mThis Is Nothing) Then
        With Form
            lMaxRight = mThis.WorkRight
            .Left = ((mThis.WorkRight) * -(.Width))
        End With
    Else
        Form.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - Form.Width
    End If
```

... however, this does not apply to the Framework, I think.

I would therefore like to ask if there is a simply method to do the same with the Microsoft .Net Framework.

Thank you!

Comment: Erm, the code pasted is for VB.Net already... It will not work in VB6.

Answer (score 0):

This code will position your form to the top right corner in vb.Net

```
 Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width, 0)
```

Comment: Assuming that the right screen has been configured as the primary monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`Screen.WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Note that this only works well when the screens are laid out in a rectangular layout (no dead areas) and horizontally.

A better method would be to enumerate the screens ([`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx)) and pick one that looks best (furthest right border? or top if there are multiple?) and then move your form to fit in that screen's bounds.